# How to control the #. Amps a USB Type-C port delivers?

Tags: windows-10, power, usb-3, usb-c

I have an Asus X556UA running Windows 10, and on it is a sticker saying it has a 4.2 Amp USB-C port. I've just bought an Anker USB-C to USB-C cable and am trying to charge my OnePlus 2 with it, but it's been plugged in for a while now and it has barely moved from 4% battery.

I have WiFi and Mobile Data off on the phone. The phone acknowledges it's charging, and it's running the latest Android via LineageOS. It estimates there's 6+ hours remaining til full.

The standard DC power cable is plugged in to the laptop, and the battery is fully charged.

**I read something about being able to set a USB-C port to either send or receive power, a.k.a. bidirectional charging.**

**Is there a setting in Computer Management, GP Edit, or similar; to control the power output?**

I'm using an [Anker Powerline+ USB Type-C to USB Type-C cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Anker-Powerline-Durability-Including-Matebook-3ft-Red/dp/B01GMZP2I6/ref=sr_1_17?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1512584662&sr=1-17&keywords=usb-c+to+usb-c) like this:

[image]

The product description for the cable says it supports Fast Charge:

> Fast Sync & Charge: Charges phones and tablets with USB-C ports at high-speed. Offers transfer speeds of 480 Mb/s

Comment: For the OnePlus 2, there is a list of compliant and tested cables that can be found [here](https://usbccompliant.com/) and a newer general list [here](https://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/IOGWYK5NXWAE/ref=pdp_new_wl), in which your cable does not seem to be listed. How much power is drawn is a matter of negotiation, where your cable apparently does pretty badly. Note that the wrong cable can fry your phone or your laptop's port.

Comment: @harrymc From the first link, there is only one C-to-C cable listed. I really doubt there is only one that is compatible. The second list contains Amazon Basic cables. The cable I have is a premium [Anker USB C-to-C Powerline+ cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Anker-Powerline-Durability-Including-Matebook-3ft-Red/dp/B01GMZP2I6/ref=sr_1_17?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1512584662&sr=1-17&keywords=usb-c+to+usb-c). I don't think the problem is with the cable. I think the laptop is only delivering 0.5 Amps.

Comment: Then again, I just spotted that it's incompatible with the OnePlus 3. Wonder if it has the same problem with the OnePlus 2 :(

Comment: USB-C compatibility seems like a very chancy subject - I think you have found out that yours is incompatible with your hardware (although too little power is better than too much...). The two lists by Benson Leung at Google are unique - he might be the only one in the world to empirically study USB-C compatibility. In most cases it's safer to use the cable by the manufacturer of the device,

Comment: [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere&hl=en) is a free app that will help troubleshoot this.  I usually run it first unplugged, then again when plugged in, and the difference between the two numbers is how much power the charger/cable is providing.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems to be very inaccurate, at least on my phone. Mostly showing around 150mA - 200mA, but it's also showing 2,000mA and 20mA.

Comment: You may be able to set a maximum power allowed out a port (a cap) but you won't be able to force a port to output a specific power level.  Electricity, as @HackSlash points out below, moves only as much power as the system *can* move, and no more.  So you have something in your system that is limiting your power (port output, cable capacity, phone's requested demand... something) and you're floating around 500mA.  If the ASUS software doesn't show a cap in place, then it's time to check different cables or if the phone is set to trickle charge (I'd bet on cables incompat with phone at this pt)

Answer (score 3):

A device will pull the maximum Amperes that it can given the conditions and no more. Looks like your device, OnePlus 2, will only pull a maximum of 1.9A even when plugged in to a 4.2A source.

Ensure you have the ASUS USB Charger + software and that it is set to fully charge external devices:

https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1010232/
(The defaulted value is set at 40%)

You can see the details of how much power is flowing by using a meter like this Satechi USB-C Power Meter Tester Multimeter:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MT8MC3N/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MT8MC3N)

I would use that meter with different cables to see if they provide different charging rates on your laptop.

Comment: I read somewhere that the OnePlus 2 supports charging at up to 3 Amps. I did have the Asus software already installed, and it was indeed set at 40%. This is just the cut-off point for quick charging if the laptop battery falls below this threshold. I've set it to the minimum though, nonetheless. That Amazon item looks cool, but for the price I might just try another cable. Failing any other bright ideas from anyone though, it looks like you'll be getting the bounty `:)`

Comment: buy multiple cables and the meter so you can do science! Then write a comprehensive review about which cables work and which ones don't. Be famous on YouTube.